# A question regarding the syntax to escape a quotation mark inside a verbatim string

Tags: c#

Why do you have to add 2 additional set of quotation marks in order to escape a set of quotation marks inside a verbatim string?

```
string s = @"""Hi"""; //Note: three quotes on either side
```

the preceding code produces the following string:
    "Hi"

Answer (score 9):

The @ symbol of course mean it's an unescaped string literal.  However, "unescaped" doesn't quite hold, because you still need some way to represent double quotes in unescaped string literals.  To do that, you just enter two double quotes together.  Your string could also be written like this:

```
string s = "\"H\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok imagine a stream of characters.

Suddenly a quote has been found. This is a start of a string literal.
We continue reading until we found another quote. 
Now two things can happen. We either find a second quote, which means we jot down one quote and continue reading. Or we find another character, which means the string has ended,

This can be shown in a simple state diagram:

```
           +--------+ --- " ---> +-------+
--- " ---> | String |            | Quote | --- any ---> end of string
           +--------+ <--- " --- +-------+
           |        ^
           |        |
           \- any -/
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but you might want to re-word so that single quote isn't taken to mean ' instead of single double-qoute.

Comment: Hope this is enough rewording.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a quote inside the string you have to escape it somehow - otherwise it would terminate the string.

MS decided to escape the quote character in a verbatim string using a sequence of 2 quote characters.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Because the quote escapes itself.